# How can i import whole json string to localStorage from file or clipboard?

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I have 39 different values in local storage, and i need to paste it from clipboard or txt file on clicking button.

If some of the keys are full with values, i can output whole localStorage to clipboard or txt file.
Here's how this data looks:

```
`{"kuzparkval7":"В809РК125","cehparkval5":"Х935ЕН125","cehparkval4":"Х935ЕН125\tООО \"ТБ Групп\"\t23776","kuzparkval17":"В337ТС","kuzparkval15":"А452НТ"}`
```

Is there a way to load all that data by clicking button after clearing localstorage?

I need to put all avaliable values at one time, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you store some kind of string in `localStorage`, something like this:

```js
const myData = { ... };
const raw = JSON.stringify(myData);
localStorage['data'] = raw;
```

Going off of that assumption, you can:

### 1. Retrieve the data from `localStorage`

```js
const raw = localStorage['data'];
const myData = JSON.parse(raw);
```

### 2. Copy the data from `localStorage` to clipboard

```js
const raw = localStorage['data'];
navigator.clipboard.writeText(raw);
```

This will write the string that was found in `localStorage` to clipboard.

### 3. Read the contents of the clipboard and write it to the `localStorage`

```js
const raw = navigator.clipboard.readText();
// This will check if raw is valid JSON
try {
  JSON.parse(raw);
  localStorage['data'] = raw;
}
catch (e) {
  // show error to user
}
```

### 4. Download the data, stored in `localStorage`, as a file

```js
function downloadText(raw, filename) {
  const blob = new Blob([ raw ], { type: 'text/plain' });
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = blob;
  a.download = filename;
  a.click();
}
```

Calling this function will prompt the user to save a file with the name `filename`, containing `raw`.

The function basically does the following:

- Converts the text to a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)
- Generates an URL for the blob
- Creates a link element (`<a href="..." download="...">`)
- Programically clicks on it

Comment: now i need to paste that data back to localstorage, is there a way?

Comment: @МаксимПилипчук yes you can, I've modified my answer

Comment: localStorage['data'] sets to the one key "data" only, but i need to paste localstorage as whole, with all avaliable keys

Comment: if you use `JSON.stringify(data)`, this will get all the data you want to store in `localStorage` and convert it to a string. Then, you can store the whole data in just one key in `localStorage`.